# how to save a string to the computer memory?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, copy, ctrl

I want to save a string to "copy" memory in computer (ctrl + c), after clicking a button.
how can I save that string to the computer memory (ctrl c) in c#?

Comment: In the time it took you to create an account, login, post your question, you could have used Google to get an answer.

Comment: The word you're looking for is 'clipboard'. If you search for "how to save string to clipboard with c#" you'll find lots of results.

Comment: thanks @user1751825 , I found the answer after searching "clipboard".

Comment: yeah I just didn't know the word "clipboard" before so I couldn't find an answer but now I got it... @WaiHaLee

Comment: Aha. You could accept the duplicate for this question if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Reference `System.Windows.Forms` if it is not already referenced in the project. Then do the magic anywhere you need:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText("your string");
```

Comment: thanks, that works :)